# Retrieving the list of y values in a function

Tags: r

I have a linear equation y=2x+1 and want to plot this with an x limit of 0 to 20. For this I have done `curve(2x+1,from=0,to=20,xlab="x",ylab="y")`. Now what I want is to extract a list of the responses (y values); so a list of 1,3,5...,41. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to extract it. You an simply compute it with a vector `0:20` and R will do the rest.

```r
2 * (0:20) + 1
#>  [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>